# aria-expanded when controlling multiple elements

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have a radio input with 2 options. Then I have 2 text inputs paired with the radio options.

When one radio option is selected, one input is shown and the other one is hidden.

I tried to achieve that with simple `aria-controls`, `aria-hidden` and `aria-expanded`. `aria-controls` simply contains 2 (space-separated) `id`s. But **how to handle `aria-expanded` if both controlled elements can have different state**?

Or is there some other ARIA role I should use in this case? `tabpanel` came to my mind, but it didn't seem right after further consideration.

Comment: Do you have a sample to view? Is it possible that you can achieve this with CSS :checked selectors? You could do `input[type=radio] + input { display: none;}` to hide it and then `input[type=radio]:checked + input { display: block;}` to show it when the radio button is checked. I suggest this as ARIA  might be overkill or a poor fit in this scenario, and `display` still addresses screen reader users (for speaking elements).

Comment: At the moment I go with similar solution using `display`. I assumed it will be better than confusing screen readers with complicated or invalid ARIA. But still wanted to know if there is some correct way of using it for this scenario.

Comment: I think not using ARIA may have been the way to go (without knowing context, but based on your description).